# macro to copy one row of data from one workbook to another

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm new to VBA want to copy one row of code that starts on C:14 to K:14 and paste it to another workbook into row C5 to K5. I have written this code but still get errors, am I on the right tracks?

```
Sub Shankill()
Dim sBook_t As String
Dim sBook_s As String

Dim sSheet_t As String
Dim sSheet_s As String

Dim lMaxRows_t As Long
Dim lMaxRows_s As Long

Dim sMaxCol_s As String

Dim sRange_t As String
Dim sRange_s As String

    sBook_t = "Shankill DR.xls"
    sBook_s = "DR complete.xls"

    sSheet_t = "Shankill DR"
    sSheet_s = "DR complete"

    lMaxRows_t = Workbooks(sBook_t).Sheets(sSheet_t).Cells(Rows.Count, "C:14").End(xlUp).Row
    lMaxRows_s = Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Cells(Rows.Count, "C5").End(xlUp).Row

    sMaxCol_s = Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Address
    sMaxCol_s = Mid(sMaxCol_s, 2, InStr(2, sMaxCol_s, "$") - 2)

    If (lMaxRows_t = 1) Then
        sRange_t = "C14:" & sMaxCol_s & lMaxRows_s
        sRange_s = "C:5" & sMaxCol_s & lMaxRows_s

        Workbooks(sBook_t).Sheets(sSheet_t).Range(sRange_t) = Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Range(sRange_s).Value

    Else
        sRange_t = "C:14" & (lMaxRows_t + 1) & ":" & sMaxCol_s & (lMaxRows_t + lMaxRows_s - 1)
        sRange_s = "C:5" & sMaxCol_s & lMaxRows_s

        Workbooks(sBook_t).Sheets(sSheet_t).Range(sRange_t) = Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Range(sRange_s).Value


    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `"C:5"`??? Similarly for others. Your range addresses are incorrect

Comment: Same while you are trying to find the last row... "C:14"?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am still getting runtime error 9?

Comment: Did you try the code that I gave below? If yes, then check the name of the worksheet/workbook. You will get `Run-time Error '9': Subscript out of Range` if excel is not able to find the specific object.

Comment: Yes I copied the code and check the names but still the error. Does the workbooks have to be saved anywhere particular or is the fact that they are both open enough?

Comment: Sorry miss type I have got it thanks very much. The code that i am copying is a result of a calculation. So is there any way of copying these results without getting #REF!?

Comment: Do you just want to copy values across?

Comment: Yes I want to copy across the values that are the result of a calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> want to copy one row of code that starts on C:14 to K:14 and paste it to another workbook into row C5 to K5.

All you need is

```
Sub Shankill()
    Dim sBook_t As String
    Dim sBook_s As String

    Dim sSheet_t As String
    Dim sSheet_s As String

    sBook_t = "Shankill DR.xls"
    sBook_s = "DR complete.xls"

    sSheet_t = "Shankill DR"
    sSheet_s = "DR complete"

    Workbooks(sBook_t).Sheets(sSheet_t).Range("C14:K14").Copy _
    Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Range("C5")
End Sub
```

**Followup from Comments**

> Yes I want to copy across the values that are the result of a calculation?

Change your code to this (Untested)

```
Sub Shankill()
    Dim sBook_t As String
    Dim sBook_s As String

    Dim sSheet_t As String
    Dim sSheet_s As String

    sBook_t = "Shankill DR.xls"
    sBook_s = "DR complete.xls"

    sSheet_t = "Shankill DR"
    sSheet_s = "DR complete"

    Workbooks(sBook_t).Sheets(sSheet_t).Range("C14:K14").Copy
    Workbooks(sBook_s).Sheets(sSheet_s).Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub macro1()
Range("A3:M6").Copy Destination:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, 1)
End Sub
```